# How to add "Custom fields" while adding steps in testlink?

Tags: testlink

**How to add "Custom fields" while adding steps in testlink?**

1. I have added custom field from "Define Custom Fields".
2. Also assigned custom field from "Assign custom field".
3. I want to view the added custom field while adding steps, after
   "Expected Results" field in grid.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible, as you can see when creating custom fields there is no option for custom fields for Test Case STEP

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the below mantis answer

http://mantis.testlink.org/view.php?id=5100

Regards

Comment: Please add answer from another resource as a quote. Because content on 3rd party resource may become unavailable someday.